# Does SyncAdapter automatically detect internet connection availability to perform Sync? Or should I manually test it?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have an SyncAdapter to sync my device data to my backend. Whenever the sync is triggered, I didn't want to check internet connection in the "onPerformSync" method. Do we have some kind of FLAG to ask SyncAdapter framework to do it automatically?

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/

According to this: 
Automated network checking
The system only runs your data transfer when the device has network connectivity.

Answer (score -1):

"Sync manager takes care of other things like checking for network connectivity before initiating transfers and retrying downloads when connectivity is dropped."

for more, checkout this video : [introducing sync adapters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DBJuYAf30w) provided by udacity course [developing android apps](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853-nd/l-1614738811/e-1664298704/m-1664298705)